# PropertyChangeCallback - whether change was from within control

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

I have a custom control with a dependency property with a PropertyChangedCallback. The value of the property could change either from within the custom control's logic, or from without (either by user interaction or by values being set from the client application).

Is there a way of telling which caused the property to change?

I tried looking at the "sender" but in each case, the sender is the Custom Control itself.

To illustrate:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedTime", typeof(DateTime?), typeof(TimePickerControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(HandleSelectedTimeChanged)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HoursProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Hours", typeof(object), typeof(TimePickerControl), new PropertyMetadata(@"", (o, e) => ((TimePickerControl)o).OnHoursChanged(o, e.OldValue)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinutesProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Minutes", typeof(object), typeof(TimePickerControl), new PropertyMetadata(@"", (o, e) => ((TimePickerControl)o).OnMinutesChanged(o, e.OldValue)));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SecondsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Seconds", typeof(object), typeof(TimePickerControl), new PropertyMetadata(@"", (o, e) => ((TimePickerControl)o).OnSecondsChanged(o, e.OldValue)));
```

So the client application could either update the `SelectedTime`, in which case the `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` would be updated by the control. This logic is handled in `HandleSelectedTimeChanged`.

However, the user could also modify one of `Hours`, `Minutes`and `Seconds` in which the `SelectedTime`would have to be updated accordingly.

As you can probably guess, this creates a bit of a loop, because a change in, say, the `Hours` would cause the `SelectedTime` callback to be triggered, which of course changes the Hours/Mins/Secs which calls their callbacks to be triggered once again.

I want to either only call the callbacks if the change came from outside the control, or else detect this within the callback and so immeadiately exit.

The only idea I've come up with so far is setting a private variable immeadiately before changing one of the properties, and within its callback exit if it's set, then clearing it immeadiately after the change, but that seems very messy to me. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Dependency properties are inside the control. If you are changing their value from within control too, then simply use some flag: set it before change, check for it in callback. Another thing is [coerce](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation#coerce-value-callbacks-and-property-changed-events).

Comment: _"As you can probably guess, this creates a bit of a loop"_ This shouldn't happen. A property changed callback will only be called when the property's value _actually changes_. So if you change the `Hours` property, its callback presumably sets the `SelectedTime` property, which will in turn set the `Hours` property value again. However, the `Hours` property value hasn't changed, so its property changed callback won't get called. I suspect your problem has more to do with your `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` dependency properties being declared as type **object**. Should they be **int**?

Comment: @StevenRands - it's not an infinite loop, and I realise what you're saying, but it has created a convoluted spaghetti flow which makes it difficult to read/debug/maintain and is potentially causing other problems within the control.

Comment: Why are your `Hours`, `Minutes` and `Seconds` dependency properties declared as type **object**? I would have expected them to be **int**s or some other primitive value type.

Comment: You have to live with the bouncing updates for all I know. DPs are not really good at being computed on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for firing the change event only from outside, I'm afraid is not possible.
It's a very common scenario that you are facing and there are some solutions.

1. The first and best solution is to avoid this scenario altogether.

In your case it means that instead of having multiple dependency properties for each component of time just write a custom value converter for each and then bind values to the single `SelectedTime` property with the required converter. I personally highly recommend this method.

2. Second approach is to change based on need.

In your case this means before triggering `UpdateHour` check if the hour should be updated or not. If not don't trigger it. It's a clean method and will cut the loop of updates but has a performance overhead.

3. The third method is having a Dirty flag.

This is somewhat what you have said. You keep a Boolean flag for `SelectedDate` with value false. when it gets changed you set it to true and in the next loop if it's true you exit and set it back to false.

As you said it's messy and unclean. But gets the job done.